# Admin-on-rest: Input validation based on field value

Tags: admin-on-rest

In a SimpleForm of an Edit view I would like to set the minimum value of the group size based on the current number of members inside.

The entity is:

```
group = {members: 3, size: 10}
```

What I'm trying to achieve looks like:

```
export const UserCreate = (props) => (
<Edit {...props}>        
    <SimpleForm>
          <DisabledInput label="Members number" 
                         source="members" />
          <NumberInput label="Group size" 
                       source="size" 
                       validation={{min: members, required: true}} />        
    </SimpleForm>
</Edit>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the [documentation](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/CreateEdit.html#validation), in the *Per Field Validation: Function Validator* part.

In a nutshell, you define a function which will take 2 parameters: the `value` to validate and `values` which contains all the form values